# How many threads can my CPU/OS handle?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I create an C++ app. How many threads can be run simultaneously?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: You can run as many threads simultaneously as the number of CPU cores you have available.

Comment: I'll go ahead and remove the "what lib do you recommend question"; library recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I remember that in 1998 I designed and implemented multi-threaded dicom workstation that had 45 threads on a 2 core system. Most of the processing was background tasks in several thread pools with each pool having a different priority. These days I have 16 times the cores but don't usually use as many threads..

Comment: To my knowledge, C++ itself doesn't impose any limit, so this would be determined by your target platform's hardware and operating system.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, your OS can handle more or less infinitely many threads. That's just a question of keeping a list of contexts / scheduling requests.

Now, *simultaneously* can mean different things to you – if you actually mean "running at exactly the same time", you of course can't have more parallel execution than cores in your CPU. But in the wider sense, as "taking turns being executed so that whilst one thread is blocked e.g. by waiting for file I/O, others can do work", there's no limit.

There's limits to usefulness – there is a handling overhead, and switching out threads leads to frequent cache invalidation, but there's no hard limits.

Comment: _"Now, simultaneously is a elastic term "_ That's arguable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ better now?

Comment: Not really. The problem is, that the question is way _too broad_ and should be closed. Also the statement _"Basically, your OS can handle more or less infinitely many threads."_ is plain wrong.

Comment: yeah, I just voted for that. Anyway, whilst this Q goes down the drain, I don't think my answer does more harm then good, so I'll leave it up and wait for it to cross the river Styx together with the question.

Comment: Also, my kernel allows me 125528 threads (ie. > 2**16), so I think for most practical purposes, "unlimited" isn't *that* wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) member function called [hardware_concurrency()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) that *returns an estimate of the number of hardware thread contexts*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main(){
    std::cout << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```